# how to hide div on variable product pages (woocommerce)

Tags: woocommerce, variable-product

I've been searching for this for like 5 or 6 days now and nothing seems to be working...

I am trying to use the code below to hide the div "" only on woocommerce variable products... but I can't seem to get it to work.

```
add_action( 'show_hide_product_variable_price', 8 );
function show_hide_product_variable_price() {
    global $product;

    if( $product->has_child() ) {
        ?>
        <style>
            .summary-price-box {
                display: none;
            }
        </style>
        <?php
    }
}
```

I have also tried using this line in the above code and still nothing...

```
if( $product->is_type('variable') ) {
```

Comment: Where did you find the `show_hide_product_variable_price` action hook?

Comment: @7uc1f3r the code was found somewhere online, it wasn't/isn't a part of my site...

Comment: Because that hook doesn't seem to exist in/for WooCommerce. So it's very hard to answer your question exactly based on that information. 
I believe you will have to add more details to your question to arrive at an answer

Comment: well let's ignore that line or this code at all... do you know at all how to hide a div only on variable product pages?

Comment: _"well let's ignore that line or this code at all"_ - That's just the problem. WooCommerce works on the basis of hooks, a hook determines which action you want to perform when or where. If the correct hook is missing but you do not indicate where you want/when you want this to happen, sufficient details are missing to answer your question. See: [WooCommerce Visual Hook Guide: Single Product Page](https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-visual-hook-guide-single-product-page/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I actually solved this earlier today.

You can either achieve this using CSS like this:

```
.product-type-variable .summary-price-box {
    display: none !important;
}
```

or you can achieve this using Javascript like this:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_get_price_html', 'lw_hide_variation_price', 10, 2);
function lw_hide_variation_price( $v_price, $v_product ) {
$v_product_types = array( 'variable');
if ( in_array ( $v_product->product_type, $v_product_types ) && !(is_shop()) ) {
return '';
}
// return regular price
return $v_price;
}
```

the css with hide the full "summary-price-box" and the javascript will hide only the "price range" or "From: $X.XX"